# Cascading Dropdown list in .NET 6 MVC getting 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0

I am trying to build a cascading dropdown list with a list of countries mapped with their corresponding states. The data is being accessed from SQL Server. I am able to build the country list using the db. However, I am unable to see the data for the states.

**CountryStateService.cs:**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<StateModel>> GetStates(int countryId) {
    var data = await (from cs in db.CountryStates
                      where cs.IdCid == countryId
                      select new StateModel 
                      {
                        stateId = cs.stateId,
                        stateName = cs.stateName,
                        IdCid = cs.IdCid
                      }).ToListAsync();

    return data;
}
```

**Home Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoadStateForCountry(int countryId) {
    var stateCollection = await _service.GetStates(countryId);
    List<StateModel> stateList = stateCollection.ToList();

    ViewBag.StateList = stateList;
    return View();
}
```

**JQuery:** [This is likely the problem as I am unable to see the data.]

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#countryDropDown').change(function() {
            // show the state dropdown only if a country is selected
            if ($('#countryDropDown option:selected').text != '') {
                $('#stateDropDown').prop('disabled', false);

                var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
                var options = `<option value=0> Select State </option>`
                
                $('#stateDropDown').empty();

                // get the location of the selected country
                $.getJSON("/Home/LoadStateForCountry/?countryId=" + selectedCountry, function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, stateDetails) {
                        options += "<option value=" + this['stateId'] + ">" + this['stateName'] + "</option>"
                    });

                    $("#stateDropDown").html(options)
                })
            
            } else {
                $('#stateDropDown').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Razor Page**

```
<select class="form-control form-control-md my-2"
        id="stateDropDown"
        placeholder="Select State"
        asp-items="@ViewBag.StateList">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to get data from `LoadStateForCountry`,you should return `stateList` in the action:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoadStateForCountry(int countryId) {
    var stateCollection = await _service.GetStates(countryId);
    List<StateModel> stateList = stateCollection.ToList();

    //ViewBag.StateList = stateList;
    return new JsonResult(stateList);
}
```